# How to call functions and create a new function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have created 2 functions that returns two dataframe.I want to create another function and merge dataframe from function1, function2 and manipulate the data there. How can i call the function and merge it together.The way i called doesn't work for me

```
def func1():
  return df1

def func2():
  return df2

def fucn3():
  func1()
  func2()
```

Comment: `df = func1().merge(func2(), left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')` Try using this inside func3(). Calling from a function does not change it much, i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear but what I think you mean is:

Use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
def func3():
  df = func1().merge(func2())
  #do something with df
  return df
```